# JPA - Extending java String,Date

Tags: java, jpa

Is it possible to declare a type

```
@????? // Embeddable? 
class MyDate extends java.util.Date implements Serializable{

    //.. lots of logic, but no new fields

}
```

and include it in a mapping

```
class Person {

   @????
   MyDate birthdate;

}
```

I have tried Embeddable/Embedded but I get this error message

```
[junit] 7109  venses  WARN   [main] openjpa.MetaData - "birhtdate" declares a null indicator column ""birthdate_null"" whose JDBC type is not compatible with the expected type "integer".
```

Comment: I don't think the answer to your question will fix your problem.

Comment: I really don't get the problem. What does "@????" mean?

Comment: Looks like a half-specified placeholder for an annotation to me.

Answer (score 0):

`String` is `final`; `Date` is not.  You cannot extend the former; you can extend the latter, but I would not recommend doing so.

Inheritance suggests that your new class has a behavior that's different from its parent.  I sincerely doubt that you have a meaningful difference in `MyDate`.  I'm betting that "lots of logic" is misguided.  For example, if you're thinking that your new class will improve on the well-understood issues with `java.util.Date`, I'd recommend trying `JODA` instead.  Use a library; don't reinvent.  I'm certain that your "lots of logic" will have no impact whatsoever on how you'll represent a `Date` or store it in a SQL database.

You ought to rethink your original intent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to define type MyDate as follows:

```
public class MyDate extends java.util.Date {
}
```

And use it as a persistent attribute in entity:

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {
    @Id private int id;

    MyDate date
}
```

This works, because it is Serializable type and consequently it is by default considered as simple type and persisted to database. No additional annotations needed. But you cannot do same with String, because you cannot extend final class.